# Azure App Authentication

Tags: azure, xamarin.android, azure-web-app-service

I have created an Xamarin Android App with an Azure App Service back end.  When I looked at securing the connection, I don't really care about individual users, but I want to make sure that only someone running my app can access the database.  Is there a way to authenticate the app itself rather than individual users?  What is the best practice in this scenario?

Comment: Where is your database stored?

Comment: It's in Azure in the same group.

Comment: I mean which of Azure service you use to store data? Azure Table, Azure SQL, Cosmos or so on.?

Comment: SQL Server Instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about user, there are a few approaches and the security level may vary. If you want to simplify integration and deployment among Azure services, you should consider using Azure AD as an identity and access management in your entirely system.  That said, your back-end and Xamarin app are authorized and authenticated via Azure AD. You need to register your native app in Azure AD which you can refer here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-application-proxy-native-client

Another approach is to use certificate-based authorization against Azure Active Directory, which is more controlled and security rather than client secret. In this case, persons installing your app must also install certificate before sending request to Azure App Service and retrieve database from Azure SQL Database. The level of authorization is free of choice, but the first gateway is always Azure AD.

Comment: I am curious.  Every time I start reading about authentication at the App level, it calls for configuring a "return url".  This seems to infer that I am creating a web app.  I am creating a Xamarin Android App.  It doesn't have any url's in it that I know of.  How do you work around this?

Comment: Url for that client app registration is only useful if your application has a sign-in URL which you need to pass the token through. While your app is not having any Sign-In url, you can even leave it as any stuff, for example `http://jimmakesawesomeapp` . You only need to retrieve access token which doesn't need this URL.

Comment: One last question (I think).  In the example you linked, I got everything set up on the Azure side, but I can't find the code mentioned at the bottom of the article in my app.  I installed the ADAL and the AAL Nuget packages, but that code doesn't show up anywhere.  Can you point me in the right direction there?

Comment: @JimWilcox how is this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-xamarin ?

Comment: I downloaded the test client and it works.  The problem is that it asks you to login.  I don't want the users to have to login.  How do allow the app itself to be the authenticated entity?

Comment: You’d need to remove ‘DirectorySeacher()’ method

Comment: Bro, it doesn't matter what I do, when it authenticates, it pulls up a login page.  I guess there is not really a way for an app to authenticate itself.